# Excel macro - unable to call cell value

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

In my worksheet some cells values are based on other cells

```
Info worksheet
A1: 5
B1: =A1
Design worksheet
A1:
```

Is there a way to copy and read the value in B1? I'm trying to use the value in a for loop, with no luck.

```
Sheets("Info").Select
For i = 1 to 5
    If Range("B" & i).Value <> 0 Then
        Range("B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Design").Range("A" & x)
        'Sheets("Design").Range("A" & x).Value = Sheets("Offerte").Range("B" & i).Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't seem to match the code well. The line

```
If Range("B" & i).Value = 1 Then
```

means that nothing will be copied in your example. It's looking for a cell with 1 in it. Why do you need that `If` statement at all?

**EDIT** I am guessing you're just checking that there's something in the cell to copy? I would probably do it this way:

```
If Trim(Range("B" & i).Value) <> "" Then
```

Also - did you miss out setting `x=1`?

Comment: Oops, made a slight mistake, but this doens't change a thing. Thanks for noticing this!

Comment: Yes I am checking whether there's a value in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it. One of them is using 'offset', which is a function that really worth understand. It basically points to a amount of rows / columns from the original cell.

```
Sub test()

    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Set oCell = Sheets("Info").Range("B1")

    x = 1

    For i = 1 To 5
        If oCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = 1 Then
            oCell.Offset(i, 0).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Design").Range("A" & x)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Besides, you can assert the value instead of using the copy property. Notice it won't work unless x is an integer > 0.

```
Sub test2()

Sheets(3).Select
x = 1
For i = 1 To 5
    If Range("B" & i).Value = 1 Then
        Sheets(4).Range("A" & x).Value = Range("B" & i).Value

        'Sheets("Design").Range("A" & x).Value = Sheets("Offerte").Range("B" & i).Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this tomorrow!